# How to execute code in epoch js,as i am new to this, i want to execute some sample charts,can anyone help in finding the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, epoch.js

```
<div id="chart" class="styles1"></div>
<button id="toggle">Switch Styles</button>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/epoch-charting@0.8.4/dist/js/epoch.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var chart = $('#chart').epoch({
    type: 'time.area',
    data: []
  });

  // The button swtiches the chart's class from styles1 to styles2 and back
  $('#toggle').click(function (e) {
    // This switches the class names...
    var className = $('#chart').attr('class');
    var newClassName = className === 'styles1' ? 'styles2' : 'styles1';
    $('#chart').removeClass(className).addClass(newClassName);

    // And this is required to see the updated styles...
    chart.redraw();
  });
</script>
```

This is the code I am using when I am executing this, I am not able to see anything, I don't know how to run even